# Let $E$ be a measurable set with finite measure and take $E = A \cup B$ where A, B disjoint. Then A, B measurable iff $m(E) = m_{*}(A) + m_{*}(B)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm working through an exercise in Heil's "Introduction to Real Analysis" and have approached a standstill. I have tried a variety of approaches (detailed below), but I haven't been able to close in on anything decisive. Assistance in the way of illuminating but not particularly revealing hints would be particularly appreciated.

**The problem.**

Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that $m(E) < \infty$. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of $E$ such that $E = A \cup B$. Show that $A$ and $B$ are measurable if and only if $m(E) = m_*(A) + m_*(B)$.

**My attempt.**

Clearly the forward appliaction is trivial, as we would have countable additivity. Thus the "meat" of the problem lies in the reverse implication. My first intuition was to attempt to establish the measurability of one, say $A$, from definitions where the measurability of $B$ would follow immediately as it is the set difference of $E$ and $A$.

For this attempt, I thought it natural to consider some closed box covering of $E$, say $\{Q_{n}\}$, such that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |Q_{n}| < m_*({A}) + m_*({B}) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then one could presumably generate a new open cover of $E$ by taking a new collection of open boxes, say $\{G_{j}\}$, such that $|G_{j}| < |Q_{j}| + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}$. This of course gives us $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |G_{n}| < m_*(A) + m_*(B) + \epsilon$.

Presumably the goal now would be to choose a certain subcollection of this collection of open boxes which is still a cover for one set, say $A$, where we would have the exterior measure of the difference between that cover and $A$ arbitrarily small. My idea here was thus to consider the subcollection of those boxes with nonempty intersection with $A$, denoted $Q_{n}^{A}$.

We want then to show that $m_*(\cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} G^{A}_{n}) - A)$ is small, which by countable subadditivity and distributing the intersection can be done by showing the exterior measure of each open cover box set difference $A$ to be small.

This is, essentially, where I am a stuck. I understand that each open box difference $G^{A}_{n} - A$ can be considered as the union of those points in each open box set difference $E$ and open box intersection $B$, where both of these *intuitively* seem to be constrainable quantities; the former as it seems reasonable to expect the ability to minimize the area of the cover which is not covering, and the latter as it also seems that the disjointness of $A$ and $B$ would somehow be conducive to this. However, how one would seek to constrain these quantities (if possible) eludes me.

**In conclusion.**

My problem seemingly is in not seeing how to constrain the aforementioned inequalities, but I am more generally scared that I may be going off in the wrong direction as the proof seems uncharacteristically difficult. Thus I am looking for hints in either the way of constraining these inequalities, or in the way of a new direction I may attempt. Of course, all help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll edit to reflect.